# SMS parsing using Node

Tags: node.js, nlp, text-parsing

I want send a json object as follows :

```
{
      "message" : "Your account XXXXXXXXXX-1234 has been credited with 10,0000 from abc@upi.com"
}
```

from the frontend. Now using node I want to parse this sms to get hold of who is the sender and other stuff. Also is there any NLP library for having different regex format to detect sender recipient or type of messages ?

Comment: What is other stuff? What have you tried so far? Is the format of the message fixed?

Comment: I was using twilio : https://www.twilio.com/blog/parsing-an-incoming-twilio-sms-webhook-with-node-js and followed the same steps mentioned over there. But they maintain a particular format and send along the reply. In my scenario the format could be haphazard.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [wink NLP for node.js](https://winkjs.org/wink-nlp/). It has a pre-trained model for detecting [entities](https://winkjs.org/wink-nlp/entities.html) like DATE, EMAIL, MONEY, CARDINAL (i.e. numbers), etc. In addition, you can train it to detect [custom entities](https://winkjs.org/wink-nlp/custom-entities.html).